# How to download a lot of documents on the terminal from a server?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget

I have to write a bash script (.sh) with less than 300 characters which downloads all of the genomes 22 in this server ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/ (the ones with fa.gz extention) and extracts them. My first though was just to write 
`wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/CHR_01/hs_alt_CHM1_1.1_chr1.fa.gz | gunzip`
but I can't do that for the 22 files. What I figured out is that all of the files have the same name except for the number next to CHM and chr. For example the tenth genome is ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/CHR_10/hs_alt_CHM1_1.1_chr10.fa.gz
I guess I have to do some kind of recursion code but I am not very experienced with bash so any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop should be enough:

```
for i in {1..22}
do
    wget "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/CHR_${i}/hs_alt_CHM1_1.1_chr${i}.fa.gz"
    gunzip "hs_alt_CHM1_1.1_chr${i}.fa.gz"
done
```

The loop index doesn't have to be just numbers, you can get the `MT`, `Un`, `X` and `Y` files as well, with:

```
for i in {1..22} MT Un X Y
```

Since the first set of numbers have to be zero-padded, you can use `printf` for that:

Or:

```
firsti="$(printf "%02d" $i)"
wget "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Homo_sapiens/CHR_${firsti}/hs_alt_CHM1_1.1_chr${i}.fa.gz"
```

You can run a test for this each loop, but it's simpler to just move the characters (`MT Un X Y`) to a separate loop using the original `wget`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry this is such a basic question. Won't I have trouble with the fact that if i<10 I need to add a 0 before the i right in front of the CHR_

Comment: That could be solved with a conditional statement. Is there any way to do that in shell?

Comment: @IvánMauricioBurbano indeed it will. I think it is simpler to use too loops than a conditional, see update.